# Powershell force convert the ConvertFrom-Json output to string which can then be used in all string operations incl. filenaming

Tags: powershell, replace, unicode, string-conversion, unicode-literals

As I have mentioned in the Question title, I want to convert the `ConvertFrom-Json` command's output to string such that, the character/string I get, should be usable such that it can be inserted into DateTime string as replacement to another character.

Currently I have following code to get the present DateTime:

```
$DTCurr = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss")
```

Now in the above code, I want to force replace the plus sign with colon sign, such that the resulting DateTime string can be used in the file-naming, so I am expecting the output(after replacement) like below:

```
07-11-2020_12:59:13
```

Now I tried this code for that forced replacement, but it doesn't work:

```
$colon = ('{ "str": "\uA789" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)
$DTCurr = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss")
$DTCurr = $DTCurr -replace "\+",$colon
Echo $DTCurr
```

This gives the output: `07-11-2020_02@{str=꞉}06@{str=꞉}28` which is ridiculous and unexpected. I can assure that `$colon` does print `:` when passed to `Echo`.

Can someone let me know what I doing wrong and help out achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry if I'm misconstruing this, but I think your end goal can be simplified by doing this

```
$DTCurr = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_hh:mm:ss")
```

or this

```
$DTCurr = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss")
$colonDT = $DTCurr -replace "\+",":"
```

but if you wanna do it your way, the reason why it's printing that output, is because it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do. You're replacing the `+` with an object  that has a property named `str` with a value of `:`. You would need to do this instead

```
$colon = ('{ "str": "\uA789" }' | ConvertFrom-Json)
$DTCurr = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss")
$colonDT = $DTCurr -replace "\+",$colon.str
Echo $colonDT
```

If I am incorrect, and you need more assistance, let me know.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't get the full idea of question. In Windows there's no allowance of using colon directly in file-naming convention, but using this Unicode character I mentioned in the question, it can interpret exactly like colon, but can fool Windows in thinking that it's not colon and can be used in file-renaming, I want exactly that. Let me know if anything still unclear.

Comment: just did a ninja edit before I saw this new comment. Any reason why you would want colons in the file name? There are better datetime formats for organizing files.

Comment: The last section should do what you initially intended though.

Comment: I guess I have bit too much of Linux/Unix fever :) They do allow literally any char incl. colons in filenames which are inherited in GitBash and Msysgits, which I wanted to repliacte with Powershell, after I was disappointed with Batch/Cmd, so I went at this adventure,and thanks you did helped me out and it worked.

Comment: Kinda off topic, but I would recommend you stick with the ISO 8601 standard (or a slight variation of it) for your filenames. unicode colon works, but it's kinda hacky. A 'pure' example would look like `20201106T1600`. Because we're (I assume) both humans, that's not so easy on the eyes, so I would opt for something like `2020-11-06_1400` or `20201106_1400` or other variants.

Comment: Yup, your suggestion is correct, but it's just that I'm habituated for years working as programmer, seeing the time string always decorated with colons, even sometimes seeing Time in other formats makes me question my code output, I've majorly worked in Unix/Linux for coding..

Answer (score 1):

[PowerShellGuy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64721376/45375) solves your problem; let me complement it:

**tl;dr**

```
# Use a [char] cast with the Unicode code point to create the char.
# of interest - no need for using JSON for that.
PS> (Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss') -replace '\+', [char] 0xA789
06-11-2020_09꞉17꞉25
```

---

**It seems that the sole reason you're using a JSON representation is to get a string with a Unicode character beyond the ANSI/ASCII-range, namely `꞉` (MODIFIER LETTER COLON, [`U+A789`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a789))**, which *looks* just like the ASCII-range `:` (COLON, [`U+003A`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3a)), but isn't.

If we assume that you need this JSON detour - which you don't - the simplest solution would have been:

```
$colonSubstitute = '"\uA789"' | ConvertFrom-Json
```

**The JSON detour isn't needed**, because **you can cast Unicode code points directly to `[char]`** ([`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char)):

```
# Directly creates Unicode char. U+A789 as a [char] (System.Char) instance.
$colonSubstitute = [char] 0xA789
```

You could cast that to a `[string]` instance, though that is often not necessary, given PowerShell's automatic, flexible type conversions (see below):

```
$colonSubstitute = [string] [char] 0xA789
```

***PowerShell [Core] v6+* *directly* supports Unicode escape sequences (akin to JSON's) inside double-quoted strings (`"..."`)**, also known as [*expandable (interpolating) strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375), using the syntax `` `u{n} ``, where `n` is the character's Unicode code point:

```
# PowerShell [Core] v6+ escape sequence
# Same as:         "$([char] 0xA789)"
$colonSubstitute = "`u{A789}"
```

Note: Unlike `[char]` casts, the `` `u{n} `` syntax also supports characters *beyond* the Unicode BMP ([Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane)), i.e., characters with code points greater than `U+FFFF` (`0xFFFF`); e.g., `` "`u{1F913}" `` for . However, in the resulting (expanded) string such characters are represented as *two* `[char]` (`System.Char`) instances, so-called *surrogate pairs*, because .NET characters are *UTF-16, i.e. *16-bit* code units* with a max. value of `0xFFFF` and therefore cannot directly represent non-BMP characters; thus, for instance, `` "`u{1F913}".Length `` yields `2`.

---

**In *Windows PowerShell***, you can **use `$(...)`**, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), **to embed `[char]` casts inside double-quoted strings (`"..."`)**:

```
$colonSubstitute = "$([char] 0xA789)"
```

Note: As discussed, `[char]` (`System.Char`) casts are limited to characters in the Unicode BMP. While characters in the non-BMP range (code points `0x10000` and up) are rare overall, you do need them for *emoji*, such as  (NERD FACE , [U+1F913](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1F913/index.htm%7D)).
Unlike the PowerShell [Core] v6+ syntax, using `[char]` casts to represent surrogate pairs is neither obvious nor convenient:

For instance, to represent , you must (a) know that non-BMP code point `U+1F913` is represented as UTF-16 surrogate pair `0xD83E`, `0xDD13`, and then embed the latter in either of these two forms:
`"$(-join [char[]] (0xD83E, 0xDD13))"` or `"$([char] 0xD83E)$([char] 0xDD13)"`

---

Finally, given PowerShell's automatic, flexible type conversions, you can directly use a `[char]` instance as the operands of the [`-replace` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator):

```
PS> (Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy_hh+mm+ss') -replace '\+', [char] 0xA789
06-11-2020_09꞉17꞉25
```

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @VickyDev; my pleasure.